# DotNet build CLI works in terminal, but not in Docker build

Tags: .net, macos, docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile

This is my first atempt with both .net core and docker. I cant figure out whats wrong.

I can run `dotnet restore` / `dotnet build`  / `dotnet run` in the terminal without any problem. The site loads up just fine. So I wanted to give docker a try (eventually running on VM in the cloud).

I run `docker build -t latest .` which results in:

```
Step 5 : RUN dotnet build
     ---> Running in e463aff85460
    Project app (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0) will be compiled because project is not safe for incremental compilation. Use --build-profile flag for more information.
    Compiling app for .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0
    /app/project.json(32,58): error NU1001: The dependency Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite >= 1.0.1 could not be resolved.

    Compilation failed.
        0 Warning(s)
        1 Error(s)

    Time elapsed 00:00:00.0174732

    The command 'dotnet build' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I've tried changing the SQLite-version in project.json without any luck.

NuGet repos:
Feeds used:

```
https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetcirelease/api/v3/index.json

https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

dotnet --version
1.0.0-preview3-003786
```

No edits to the dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:latest

COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN ["dotnet", "restore"]

RUN ["dotnet", "build"]

EXPOSE 5000/tcp

CMD ["dotnet", "run", "--server.urls", "http://*:5000"]
```

Tried creating a .dockerignore after some Googling without any luck:

```
.git
Dockerfile
.DS_Store
.gitignore
README.md
project.lock.json
```

Im on latest macOS (10.12).

package.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SQLite": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Design": "1.0.1"
  },

  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "precompile": [ "dotnet bundle" ],
    "prepublish": [ "bower install" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  },

  "tooling": {
    "defaultNamespace": "MyFirstApp"
  }
}
```

Output after trying to build docker container:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 26.39 MB
Step 1 : FROM microsoft/dotnet:latest
 ---> 96d122fe36cb
Step 2 : WORKDIR /root
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0c5317108a5b
Step 3 : COPY bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.0/publish/ /root/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d79700fa6c36
Step 4 : ENTRYPOINT dotnet /root/MyProject.dll
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a99f30826ddd
Successfully built a99f30826ddd
```

Answer (score 1):

The image microsoft/dotnet:latest is not designed for build but only for runtime.

The best way to publish .net core application into the docker is:

1. `dotnet restore`
2. `dotnet publish`
3. `docker build -t your-tag` with Dockerfile like:

   ```
   FROM microsoft/dotnet:latest
   WORKDIR /root
   COPY bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.0/publish/ /root/
   ENTRYPOINT dotnet /root/[your-project-name].dll
   ```

   where bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.0/publish is your real publish path.

In case you want build .net core app in docker use this image:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:onbuild
```

The differences between image versions are explained [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/dotnet/)

Regards

Comment: A better link describing the differences between the images https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/docker/building-net-docker-images

Comment: @DannyThunder yes - I used docker instead of dotnet, thanks. It's late night .. Edited

Comment: No executable found matching command "dotnet-/root/app/MyProject.dll", Trying everything, but i get stuck with this error.

Comment: @DannyThunder After running the publish command, what's written on the output in green? It's the really .dll located at the path or at the path you provided? -- IMHO the .dll after publish should be copied to /root folder directly (without app/). What your ENTRYPOINT looks like?

Comment: Added output in original post. Trying to find out how to display the files in my container, no success in finding a simple way (like ls -l)

Comment: First, change the entrypoint to `ENTRYPOINT sleep 300`. Then build it and run it. You have now 5 minutes to investigate. Run `docker ps` to obtain `CONTAINER ID` of your running image. Then execute `docker exec -it <container id here> /bin/bash`. Now you're in the container an you can do things inside. Ensure that MyProject.dll is present in /root or if it hasn't different name.